# Retaining the previous date in R

Tags: r, data-munging

I got stuck at a fairly easy data munging task. I have a transactional data frame in R that resembles this one:

```
id<-c(11,11,22,22,22)
dates<-as.Date(c('2013-11-15','2013-11-16','2013-11-15','2013-11-16','2013-11-17'), "%Y-%m-%d")
example<-data.frame(id=id,dates=dates)

  id      dates
1 11 2013-11-15
2 11 2013-11-16
3 22 2013-11-15
4 22 2013-11-16
5 22 2013-11-17
```

I'm looking for a way to retain the date of the previous transaction. The resulting table would look like this:

```
previous_dates<-as.Date(c('','2013-11-15','','2013-11-15','2013-11-16'), "%Y-%m-%d")
example2<-data.frame(id=id,dates=dates, previous_dates=previous_dates)

  id      dates previous_dates
1 11 2013-11-15           <NA>
2 11 2013-11-16     2013-11-15
3 22 2013-11-15           <NA>
4 22 2013-11-16     2013-11-15
5 22 2013-11-17     2013-11-16
```

I looked into other similar problems and one solution that is very close to what I want is:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(example)

prev_date <- function(x) c(x[1],x)

dt[,prev:=prev_date(dates), by=id]
```

The problem with this one is that if there is no previous date (*like in the case of id=11 dates=2013-11-15*) the function would output the same date resulting in:

```
  id      dates previous_dates
1 11 2013-11-15     2013-11-15
2 11 2013-11-16     2013-11-15
```

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
example$previous_dates <- ave(example$dates, example$id,
                 FUN=  function(dt) c.Date( c(NA, dt[-length(dt)])
                                              ))
> example
  id      dates previous_dates
1 11 2013-11-15           <NA>
2 11 2013-11-16     2013-11-15
3 22 2013-11-15           <NA>
4 22 2013-11-16     2013-11-15
5 22 2013-11-17     2013-11-16
```

Playing around with the classes of Date objects  .... this also works:

```
example$previous_dates <- ave(example$dates, example$id,
             FUN=  function(dt) structure( 
                                  c(NA, dt[-length(dt)]),
                                  class="Date" )  )
```

Comment: Actually your solution works faster than Roland's when applied to a large dataset.

Comment: @NikolayNenov If your dataset is really large and there are many ids, you should use data.table. I only didn't show yesterday how to do that because I didn't find a solution to conserve the Date class and would have needed to do something like Dwin used in the first revision of his answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(plyr)
example <- ddply(example, .(id), transform, 
                                  previous_dates=c(as.Date(NA), head(dates, -1)))
  id      dates previous_dates
1 11 2013-11-15           <NA>
2 11 2013-11-16     2013-11-15
3 22 2013-11-15           <NA>
4 22 2013-11-16     2013-11-15
5 22 2013-11-17     2013-11-16
```

Comment: I like the as.Date(NA) strategy. I needed to re-Date with as.Date.numeric after the c() removed my Date-class.

Comment: @DWin `c.Date(NA, head(dates, -1))` would also work.

Comment: So its an S3 dispatch phenomenon? First argument wins and NA "has no class".

Comment: Basically. However, `NA` has a class.

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach:

```
transform(example, previous_dates = ave(dates, id, FUN = 
                                         function(x) x[c(NA, (seq_along(x)-1))]))

  id      dates previous_dates
1 11 2013-11-15           <NA>
2 11 2013-11-16     2013-11-15
3 22 2013-11-15           <NA>
4 22 2013-11-16     2013-11-15
5 22 2013-11-17     2013-11-16
```